# Releasing for Python (with pbr): version not generated

Tags: python, git, release, setup.py, pypi

This is something I am new to, but I made a small Python library on Github and looking to release it on PyPI. The [pbr](https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/latest/) library is supposed to make things easier by taking versions from git tags, etc.

However, `pbr` is not deriving the version number from the git tag.

Here is what I tried:

- Push code to Github and create a release with semantic tagname `v1.0.0`
- Make sure the tag is also in my local repository: `git fetch --tags`
- Generate and upload a release: `python setup.py sdist upload -r pypi`

The release is made and `pbr` seems to works fine, only the version number is `0.0.1.dev2`. The last number seems to increase with the number of commits.

I have tried to explicitly checkout the revision at the tag: `git checkout tags/v1.0.1`, but that made no difference.

Why is `pbr` not following my Git tags?

edit: this is the code on [Github](https://github.com/glueball-css/glueball-hsla)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: `pbr` expects Git tags to be **signed** for use in calculating versions.

See https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/latest/user/features.html#version

You have to sign you tags with GPG:

```
git tag -s $version
```

Comment: I have now created a GPG signed tag and a new commit.The tag gets verified in Github, so I am positive that the GPG setup is fine. pbr happily continues with `0.0.1.dev5`, so that was not enough to solve it.

Comment: I got it to work with signed tags, although not consistently. Will update if I find out more.

Comment: Any new info here? I am also struggeling with signed tags not being accepted.

Comment: Sorry for not following up, never found the exact reason it did not work. I would suggest using annotated tags. I *think* signed tags count as annotated automatically, but just to make sure you can annotate them explicitly. Let me know if that makes a difference for you.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure if your version tag contains a 'v' that you use pbr >= 4.0.0, for me this was the problem in deploying to pypi from travis. Updating pbr before deploying fixed that.

See also:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/pbr/+bug/1744478
- https://github.com/openstack-dev/pbr/commit/4c775e7890e90fc2ea77c66020659e52d6a61414